Log4j2 pattern: Escape double-quotes in passed-down message values
We are using log4j2 in our microservices, which all have patterns that produce key-value pairs where values are enclosed in double-quotes so they can automatically be parsed by security tools (in fact, the quoting is a mandate by our IT Sec group).
Example (only two keys shown for for clarity):
<property name="pattern">dateTime=&quot;%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}&quot; msg=&quot;%msg%throwable&quot;%n</property>

Our code produces logs in the following fashion...
log.info("Request started");
log.debug("Data received: {}, dataAsJsonObject);
log.error("Reading file failed", ex);

... which will then produce messages like this:
dateTime="2024-06-25 13:05:12.984" msg="Request started"

The problem is when log messages passed down from code contain double-quotes (like when printing out JSON content. They "mess up" the quoting sequence in the printed log message. As you can see in this example, the value of the msg key now is reduced to Data received: {.
dateTime="2024-06-25 13:05:12.984" msg="Data received: {"key": "value"}"

Is there any way to have log4j2 escape double-quotes in the values passed into the format string (e.g. " -> \" and \ -> \\), for a result like this?
dateTime="2024-06-25 13:05:12.984" msg="Data received: {\"key\": \"value\"}"

Note: To be clear, I am not talking about escaping double-quotes in the format pattern itself, but in the values that get passed into the formatter that expands the pattern with passed-down log values.

Needs a [mre] including how to generate the values.

The value is JSON isn't?

Probably the best thing would be a customized version of one of the log4j2 API classes. But you could try the crude message = message.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"")); before logging it

I'd really like to avoid having to put escape logic into production code.

@aled I edited the question and added logging code examples.

For a JSON object escaping would be wrong. You need to write it to a string using a JSON parser so it is automatically escaped.

I finally found Log4j2's comprehensive documentation of log4j2. Under patterns, there are two conversion patterns that should work:

Encode: msg=&quot;%encode{%msg}{JSON}&quot;
Replace with regex: msg=&quot;%replace{%msg}{\s}{}&quot;

Note: The above regex only removes spaces. I haven't had time yet to figure out a regex pattern (or two) that escapes double-quotes and backslashes.

I haven't had time yet to figure out a regex pattern (or two) that escapes double-quotes and backslashes. Well I've already given you one for the former, though from your question, it seemed that only the former was necessary..?

Both double-quotes AND backslashes need to be escaped. Double-quotes are the "primary" problem, but once you escape double-quotes with backslashes, it follows that backslashes need to be escapes with double backslashes. That's why I didn't incorporate your regex, yet.

I'm not sure it does follow. Are you perhaps getting confused between strings in the Java code editor and actual strings?
